# Why does SCP fail when "RequestTTY force" option is enabled?

Tags: ssh, files, tty, scp, openssh

In my SSH config file, I have to enable the `RequestTTY force` for some important reasons. And currently my config file looks like this:

```
Host x.x.x.x
    HostName yyyy
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
    RequestTTY force
    IdentityFile ~/path/id_rsa
```

But now when I execute an `scp` command, it completes but creates an empty file on the destination path and below is the log that it generates:

```
debug2: channel 0: read<=0 rfd 4 len 0
debug2: channel 0: read failed
debug2: channel 0: close_read
debug2: channel 0: input open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: ibuf empty
debug2: channel 0: send eof
debug2: channel 0: input drain -> closed
debug2: channel 0: write failed
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: send eow
debug2: channel 0: output open -> closed
```

But if I comment out the `RequestTTY force` option in the config file, it executes properly and also copies the file properly.

Why does this behaviour occur?
Can anyone provide me with a workaround so that I won't have to disable the `RequestTTY force` option and also the file would be copied properly?

Comment: Define "some important reasons".

Comment: In my code I execute sudo commands over SSH. Normally they work fine but when it comes to RHEL machines, it throws an error regarding TTY allocation. So I have to force the allocation for my codes to run on RHEL machines too.

Comment: Instead of using `force` you can just use `yes`, and it normally detected tty pretty well, and scp will work too

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many possible solutions for that:

- You can configure `sudo` not to require tty: `RequireTTY` in `/etc/sudoers`
- You can force tty allocation on command-line in these specific cases, where you need it: `ssh -tt host command`
- You can tell `scp` not to allocate TTY by `-T` or `-o RequestTTY=no` command-line option: `scp -T file host:path/` or `scp -o RequestTTY=no file host:path/`

The reasons why does it happen are already explained. You spoil binary protocol by TTY control characters and vice versa.

Answer (score 6):

1. SCP protocol is binary one.
2. With TTY enabled, the control characters have their meaning.

So as soon as the TTY sees a character in the SCP protocol binary data that appears as a control character, it interprets it. Particularly as soon as there's `^C` (ASCII 0x03), it aborts the SCP process.

Use `ssh -t` to force TTY for interactive sessions, instead of forcing it globally using `RequestTTY`.

Comment: So what would be a possible solution for this?

Comment: Why do you need the `RequestTTY`?

Comment: In my code I execute sudo commands over SSH. Normally they work fine but when it comes to RHEL machines, it throws an error regarding TTY allocation. So I have to force the allocation for my codes to run on RHEL machines too.

Comment: You may use `scp` in separeate call without tty allocation

Comment: Cannot you use `ssh -t` instead of global configuration?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I need 'RequestTTY force' at all times. Cannot afford to disable it.

Comment: That does not answer "why?" If you do not tell us, we cannot help you.

Comment: Why not run scp with that option set to no? You can even alias it `alias scp='scp -oRequestTTY=no'` Edit:Jakuje has a better option below: `scp -T`.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the following worked:

```
Host *.bla.fasel.com
   User horst
   RequestTTY yes
```

`ssh` with `sudo -i`:

```
$ ssh guenther.bla.fasel.com sudo -i
horst@guenther.bla.fasel.com's password:
root@guenther.bla.fasel.com:~#
```

`scp` with username/password auth:

```
$ scp guenther.bla.fasel.com:/etc/passwd .
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a    terminal.
horst@guenther.bla.fasel.com's password:
passwd
```